# Laravel Validation Passing Variable to Rule::in() method

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I am importing a Excel file in Laravel, It is working fine. I need some validation like whether team ids are available in `database` or not. I make a query each time file uploaded and create an array and then implode it to pass in rule condition. Can you please help. Is it possible to pass and variable to rule method as am trying to do in my code?

Thanks in advance.

```
public function rules(): array
{

.......
//Some Codes here
.....

$team_id = implode("', '", $team_id_array);

    return [

         '*.ext_or_int' => Rule::in(['Internal','External']),             
         '*.team_id' => Rule::in(['$team_id']),             
    ];
}
```

Comment: try with exists rule for database check. like `'*.team_id' => 'exists:table_name,column_name'`

Comment: Okay thanks. But I have two tables one is scopes and second is teams. When I import excel to scopes, I want to check team_id field. Every team id must be available in teams tables for that clients.

Comment: I found the solution. Now my code is like below:

'*.team_id' => Rule::exists('teams', 'id')->where(function ($query) {
 $query->where([
  ['client_id', $client_id],
  ['status', 1],
   ] );
}),